# Find files that have the same name as the directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, find, diff

I have the next problem:

Directory `Example1` has three files: `Example1`, `Things` and `Pictures`.

Directory `Example2` has three files: `Example2`, `Example3` and `Pictures`.

I need  a list showing only the files that match the directory name, this is: `Example1` and `Example2`. I have tried with diff, find, locate and ls... but I have not achieved anything.

Comment: Where do you want to find these? In the entire filesystem? In one directory only?

Comment: Hi!! Only in one directory. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since there are generally fewer directories than files, let's look for all directories and then test whether they contain the required filename.

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        filepath="$dirpath/${dirpath##*/}"
        [ -f "$filepath" ] && printf "%s\n" "$filepath"
    done' sh {} +
```

This would print the pathnames of all regular files (and symbolic links to regular files) that is located in a directory that has the same name as the file.

The test is done in a short in-line `sh -c` script that will get a number of directory pathnames as arguments.  It iterates over each directory pathname and constructs a file pathname with the name that we're looking for.  The `${dirpath##*/}` in the code could be replaced by `$(basename "$dirpath")`.

For the given example directory structure, this would output

```
./Example1/Example1
./Example2/Example2
```

To just test for *any name*, not just regular files, change the `-f` test to a `-e` test.

Comment: It doesn't work for me I don't know where the error might be Thanks

Comment: @ChangKo Does it display an error, or does it just not output anything? If I run that exact code, I do find occurrences of files that are located in directories that have the same name as the file.

Comment: @ChangKo The code will only look at directories _below_ the current directory. Use `"$HOME"` (or `~`) in place of the initial `.` to look in or below your home directory.

Comment: It just doesn't do anything. I don't know why. Thanks for your time. I have also tried $ home.

Comment: @ChangKo When you say "files" in the question, you you actually _mean_ file? The name `Pictures` seems to be the name of a _directory_. Test my code again, but change `-f` to `-e` (so that you have `[ -e "$filepath" ]`).  This will detect any type of name, not just names of files. Also note that if you _retype_ the code, all quotes needs to be _exactly_ as shown in the answer.

Comment: @ChangKo If that does not work, then I'd expect that none of the other answers would work either (they are all correct).

Comment: You are absolutely right, it works perfectly.
But it only looks for me if I'm in the directory /, when I'm in the / home directory or change . (point) through another directory does nothing. I have changed permissions just in case. Anyway, as I said, it works perfectly- Thanks

Comment: It is done!!
I have removed the point and I have not put anything and it goes perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: @ChangKo The dot means "the current directory". If you remove it, and if you use GNU `find` (e.g. on a Linux system), this would be _the same_ as using `.` as the search path (that means, it changes nothing). The `.` in my command is where `find` should start searching. If you use `find ~ ...` it starts searching in your home directory.

Answer (score 19):

You can easily match file names that have the same name as the containing directory with a regex using a backreference. These are file names of the form `what/ever/something/something` where the two `something` parts are identical and don't contain a slash. In BRE regex syntax, `[^/]*` matches any string that doesn't contain a slash, `\(/[^/]*\)` matches a slash followed by any number of non-slash characters and makes the whole thing a group, and `\1` matches the same text that is matched by the first group, therefore `\(/[^/]*\)\1` matches two path segments with the same name. Add `.*` at the beginning to match the previous directory components.

With GNU find, FreeBSD find, macOS find or any other `find` that supports `-regex`:

```
find . -regex '.*\(/[^/]*\)\1'
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know that you could have a backreference in the same `find -regex`.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation of this regex ?

Comment: @forzagreen Done

Answer (score 5):

**Use `find -exec`:**

```
find . -type f \
  -exec sh -c '[ "$(basename "$1")" = "$(basename "$(dirname "$1")")" ]' find-sh {} \; \
  -print
```

The `-print` will only execute when the result of the `[ ... ]` inside the `-exec sh -c '...'` is true.

**Output:**

```
./Example1/Example1
./Example2/Example2
```

Comment: `find -exec .. \;` is slow

Comment: How many processes does this fork for a tree of 1000 files?